# Excel - N/a In cell causes formula searching range to break

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, array

I have a formula in excel checking a range and returning only cells which contain `Monday`.

However, some cells in the range have an `#N/A` and this is causing my formula to break.

If I remove them then it works perfectly again, I don't want to have to constantly be checking for `N/A'`s though so is there any way to prevent these from affecting my formula?

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$1000,SMALL(IF($D$2:$D$1000 = "Monday", ROW(A$2:A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")
```

There is my formula in case it is something specifically to do with that. I have noticed that it only seems to break if the If statement comes across a cell with the `N/A`.

For example if there was one in cell `A500`, I can keep the index range going up to `1000`, but have to change the ranges inside the If statement to end at 499.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put the error check into the part that is using an array where you will find the error.

In your example column D is returning the Error, and that is used within the `SMALL` part of your formula,

So wrap the array part of `SMALL` into an `IFERROR`, and rather than return "", return a large number, as you are only looking for the SMALL, i.e 9999999 will be larger than any row in range A2:A1000.

Hope that made sense, anyways, see below for result:

```
{=IFERROR((INDEX(A$2:A$1000,SMALL(IFERROR(IF($D$2:$D$1000="Monday",ROW(A$2:A$1000)-ROW(A$2)+1),999999999),ROWS(A$2:A2)),1)),"")}
```